# Flutter String Concatenation breaking when last string is file extension

Tags: string, flutter, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate some strings which will eventually be part of a URL, but the result of the concatenation is always missing the last String which is a file extension.

I've tried all the official ways of concatenating. Here is my latest attempt when I tried to merge the strings by using the join method on a String List.

```
      String? resColor = color?.label;
      String? resCategory = category?.label;

      print(resColor!.length);
      List<String> refSplit = [
        'previewAssets/',
        resCategory!,
        '/',
        resColor!,
        '.jpg'
      ];

      for (int i = 0; i < refSplit.length; i++) {
        print(refSplit[i]);
      }
      String ref = refSplit.join('');
      print(refSplit);
      print(ref);
```

My excepted outcome is obviously that ref would contain all items from refSplit. But it doesn't.

Here is the output from the prints: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9LLq.png)

Im knida new to flutter but I feel like concatenating strings shouldn't be this hard, so I'm probably missing something obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*edit: So I've continued to look into this and I'm pretty sure the problem is with resColor, which suspiciously has a length of 4 when it should be 3. So my current guess is that it contains some invisible endline like char at the end which is messing up the concat.

**edit: By removing the last char of resColor, it fixed the issue. This is the code I used to do that: `resColor = resColor!.substring( 0, resColor!.length -1);`

Comment: What other method did you used?

Comment: I tried using the + operator, as well as combining them as string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems to work fine in dartpad

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> refSplit = [
    'previewAssets/',
    'something',
    '/',
    '109',
    '.jpg'
  ];
  String ref = refSplit.join("");
  print(ref);
}
```

[image: preview]

Try to restart your IDE and try again.

Comment: Yup, this works for me too. Thanks to this I realized that the issue wasn't the actual concatenation, but rather within the strings I was trying to concat.  Like I mentioned above, resColor contained some wierd last char which was causing the issues. Thanks for the help!